# Drag and drop with JavaFX TreeView

Tags: events, javafx, treeview

I implemented Drag and Drop feature as recommended in other threads in this forum. I have a `cellFactory` on a `TreeView` and set the events on the cells.

```
tvProject.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<PlanningItem>, TreeCell<PlanningItem>>() {
        @Override
        public PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell call(TreeView<PlanningItem> siTreeView) {
            final PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell source = new PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell();
            final PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell target = new PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell();

            source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture */
                    System.out.println("onDragDetected");

                    /* allow any transfer mode */
                    Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                    /* put a string on dragboard */
                    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    content.putString(source.getText());
                    db.setContent(content);

                    event.consume();
                }
            });

            target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                    /* data is dragged over the target */
                    System.out.println("onDragOver");

                    ...

                    event.consume();
                }
            });
```

The `setOnDragDetected` is executed/hit as wanted but all other events are NOT (I did not post them all here: `setOnDragOver`,`setOnDragEntered`,`setOnDragExited`,`setOnDragDropped`,`setOnDragDone`).
The `PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell` is a custom implementation of a treecell as follows:

```
public class PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell extends CheckBoxTreeCell<PlanningItem> {

    public PlanningCheckBoxTreeCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(PlanningItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setText(null);
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE** `PlanningItem`:

```
    package at.v2c2.testplaygroundui;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class PlanningItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Double scene = null;
    private Integer path = null;
    private String move = null;

    /**
     * @return the scene
     */
    public Double getScene() {
        return scene;
    }

    /**
     * @param scene the scene to set
     */
    private void setScene(Double scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    /**
     * @return the path
     */
    public Integer getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * @param path the path to set
     */
    private void setPath(Integer path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     * @return the move
     */
    public String getMove() {
        return move;
    }

    /**
     * @param move the move to set
     */
    private void setMove(String move) {
        this.move = move;
    }

    public PlanningItem(Object item) {
        super();
        if (item instanceof Double) {
            setScene((Double) item);
        } else if (item instanceof Integer) {
            setPath((Integer) item);
        } else if (item instanceof String) {
            setMove((String) item);
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE** The MCVE:

```
    package at.v2c2.testplaygroundui;

    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public final class TestplaygroundUi extends Application {

    private final DataFormat objectDataFormat = new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public TestplaygroundUi() {
        // empty.
    }

    /**
     * @param args Program arguments.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TreeItem<PlanningItem> treeItemRoot = new TreeItem<>(new PlanningItem(1.0));

        TreeItem<PlanningItem> nodeItemA = new TreeItem<>(new PlanningItem(2));
        TreeItem<PlanningItem> nodeItemB = new TreeItem<>(new PlanningItem(2));
        treeItemRoot.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemA, nodeItemB);

        TreeItem<PlanningItem> nodeItemA1 = new TreeItem<>(new PlanningItem("A1"));
        TreeItem<PlanningItem> nodeItemB1 = new TreeItem<>(new PlanningItem("B1"));
        nodeItemA.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemA1);
        nodeItemB.getChildren().addAll(nodeItemB1);

        TreeView<PlanningItem> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeItemRoot);

        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<PlanningItem>, TreeCell<PlanningItem>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<PlanningItem> call(TreeView<PlanningItem> siTreeView) {
                final TreeCell<PlanningItem> cell = new TreeCell<>();

                cell.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture */
                        System.out.println("onDragDetected");

                        /* allow any transfer mode */
                        Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

                        /* put a string on dragboard */
                        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

                        content.put(objectDataFormat, cell.getItem());
                        // content.putString("Hello");// cell.getText());
                        db.setContent(content);

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data is dragged over the target */
                        System.out.println("onDragOver");

                        /*
                         * accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node and if it has a string data
                         */
                        if (event.getGestureSource() != cell && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                            /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                        }

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
                        System.out.println("onDragEntered");
                        /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
                        if (event.getGestureSource() != cell && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                            // target.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        }

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("onDragExited");

                        /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
                        // target.setFill(Color.BLACK);

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data dropped */
                        System.out.println("onDragDropped");
                        /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                        boolean success = false;
                        if (db.hasString()) {
                            cell.setText(db.getString());
                            success = true;
                        }
                        /*
                         * let the source know whether the string was successfully transferred and used
                         */
                        event.setDropCompleted(success);

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                cell.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
                        System.out.println("onDragDone");
                        /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
                        if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                            cell.setText("");
                        }

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });

                return cell;
            };
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(treeView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test TreeView");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: No onDragDropped is fired]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're creating 2 cells in your factory. Only one of them can be returned an the other is simply discarded. I assume you return `source` and discard `target`. The thing you should do instead is registering ***all*** the event handlers for the cell you return since the cell may both serve as source and as target for the drag/drop gesture. The declaration of `target` in the factory method body should be removed, since you cannot simply hardcode a source/target node combination...

Comment: I have registered all events on the only cell now, but still just setOnDragDetected is fired...

Comment: This could be the result of using `null` or the empty string as content for the dragboard... If using some other content does not fix your issue, please update the question with your new code and include the `return` statement of the factory.

Comment: If I use a `DataFormat objectDataFormat = new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");` as key together with a custom PlanningItem as value and put them into the ClipBoard, i.e. `content.put(objectDataFormat, cell.getItem());`, then the `onDragDropped` is again not fired any more...

Comment: I have provided a MCVE now :) I would also provide the program as a zip file, but I  could not elicit how to attach a file ...

Comment: Also `onDragDropped`? I provided a screenshot...

Comment: yeah - sure, why should it not? Provided the drop is allowed (which it isn't in your example ;)

Comment: Solution: `if (event.getGestureSource() != cell
                                && event.getDragboard().hasContent(objectDataFormat)) {`. The `acceptTransferModes` was not hit.